# htacess remove a string of characters and redirect to a specific url

Tags: string, .htaccess

i want to redirect:

http://www.example.com/example-folder/%E2%80%8Bvirginia.html

into:

http://www.example.com/example-folder/virginia.html

thus only removing this part:
%E2%80%8B from the first url

---

by the way, if the first link is pasted in firefox, the characters doesnt change. but on chrome the characters i want to remove becomes a square character.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these `%E2%80%8B`, `virginia.html` and `example-folder` always the same fixed strings? If not, what's the pattern that identifies each one?

Comment: hello faa. virginnia.html and example-folder is fixed in its location. its only %E2%80%8B that should be removed in the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found on another site, thanks to mslina2002:

for those looking for a solution check the thread i posted before or make this your guide(from mslina2002)

```
# for url like www.example.com/my-file-name/
# bad backlink site is doing this:
# string %E2%80%8B is randomly added to slug url
# fix will redirect back to www.example.com/my-file-name/
#
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)\%E2%80%8B(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

works like a charm.

the issue was the dreaded "zero-width space" or